# Current State concept in Blockchain

Tags: blockchain

Anybody explains what does this statement means,
'Blockchain is not a snapshot of current state'.

Comment: I think we need some context. Where did you read it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it refers to the fact that a blockchain's state consists of transactions and the blockchain itself doesn't have any data reserved for storing "current state" - even if node clients have such concepts.

So in order to get the "current state" for a blockchain a client has to start with the very first transaction in the blockchain and execute every single transaction that appears in blocks. Whenever a new block arrives with new transactions they need to be executed and the "current state" changes.

If you stop your client from synchronizing the blockchain you get a "current state" - a snapshot of the blockchain's state at the time of the last block you have. But the blockchain itself continues evolving and only by executing the latest transactions you can reach the most recent state.